# How do I migrate my autocomplete list from Windows Mail to Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, autocomplete, windows-mail

I am in a difficult position. I am trying to switch to using Thunderbird, but my major problem is that I don't have a real address book because I relied heavily on the address autocomplete. I don't really understand the process behind how it worked, but Mail allowed me to just type in "Mom" for instance and it would bring up my mom's email address. I understand that this has something to do with the autocomplete list, but I have no idea where this is stored on the computer. How can I get this information over to Thunderbird?

Comment: For Outlook, see https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3892-outlook-copy-export-autocomplete-list-file.html  and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-copy-the-autocomplete-list-to-another-computer-83558574-20dc-4c94-a531-25a42ec8e8f0 . If that works, you'd likely need to import addresses manually, since TBird offers only "Import accounts, address books, and messages from Outlook."

Comment: Do you refer to Outlook, to the Mail and Calendar app or to the discontinued Windows Live Mail? Which is your Windows version? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I am talking about the Mail and Calendar app. I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to solve this myself. I agree with you that the autocomplete list is harvested from sent emails and is not derived from 'People'.
A number of websites report that autocomplete list for Windows Mail is stored in \Users<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.People_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TempState
but mine was empty.
Also https://darkdefender.medium.com/windows-10-mail-app-forensics-39025f5418d2 reports that the contacts are stored in AppData\Local\Comms\Unistore\data\2 but again mine was empty even though I have many autocomplete entries.

This is not a complete answer but added in the hope that it might guide others to a solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).